# Wrong date of recurring events are added in google calendar

Tags: google-calendar-api, recurring-events

When I add an recurring event from one timezone, the UNTIL date shows correctly but the events shown are wrong

For example,

```
{ 
   "end": 
    {  "dateTime": "2017-09-26T22:10:00",  "timeZone": "America/New_York" }, 
   "start": 
    {  "dateTime": "2017-09-26T21:50:00",  "timeZone": "America/New_York" }, 
   "recurrence": [  "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20170929;" ], 
   "summary": "LEAVE. ", 
   "location": "New Tover"
}
```

When I add this, it shows till 28 only but not till 29.
If I set it as a day extra, it takes my offset value of timezone and recurring event differs while adding.

For example, if my timezone is `Asia/Culcutta`, and if i add a recurring event anytime between morning 12am-5:30am, it shows till 30th and other events till 29th. Please help.

Comment: if you set it to UNTIL=20170930, does it shows until 29?

Comment: Yes it shows but the problem is, it depends on timezone. If my timezone is `Asia/Culcutta`, if I add a recurring event from 12am-5:30am it shows till 30th but after that it shows till 29th. Why does it take 5.30 time offset value for recurring data?

Comment: different timezones, different times

Comment: No i'm saying its happening for all recurring event, if i give my timezone as `America/Los_Angeles`, the recurring event shows one day extra for time greater than 8pm-12am, if i schedule recurring events in other time, it works fine.